# Proving simple inequality in Ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm having trouble with some pretty simple proofs in Coq, using the MathComp library for reflection.

Suppose I want to prove this Lemma:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrnat.

Lemma example m n: n.+1 < m -> n < m.
Proof.
      have predn_ltn_k k: (0 < k.-1) -> (0 < k).
          by case: k.
      rewrite -subn_gt0 subnS => submn_pred_gt0.
      by rewrite -subn_gt0; apply predn_ltn_k.
Qed.
```

This approach seems a little "unorthodox" to me for such a simple task. Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: Please always include the list of imports when you're posting a code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. Your lemma is a special case of `ltnW : forall m n, m < n -> m <= n`:

```
Lemma example n m : n.+1 < m -> n < m.
Proof. exact: ltnW. Qed.
```

This works because `n < m` is actually syntactic sugar for `n.+1 <= m`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't practiced ssreflect a lot so I can't really tell whether this can be golfed down but basically the idea is that `n < n.+1 < m`:

```
Require Import mathcomp.ssreflect.ssrnat.
Require Import mathcomp.ssreflect.ssrbool.
Require Import mathcomp.ssreflect.ssreflect.

Lemma example m n: n.+1 < m -> n < m.
Proof.
move => ltSnm; apply: ltn_trans; by [apply ltnSn | apply ltSnm].
Qed.
```

Comment: Tip: change your three first lines into: `From mathcomp Require Import ssrnat ssrbool ssreflect.`